# How to build accumulated sum per day in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel worksheet where I write down all the hours per day I work on my project.
During one day I just work some minutes here and there.

In one column of my sheet I would like to have the accumulated / added hours I worked at that specific day.

So once a row with `day`, `start`, and `end` is complete, the referring `accumulated hours per day` for this new row should appear.
I would like to have this cell prefilled, so that I do not have to make any manual adjustments of the contents of this cell.

How has a formula in column `accumulated hours per day` have to look like to achieve this?

[image: I need a formula for the rightmost column]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,0,D1)+C2-B2
```

Ideally, I'd suggest avoiding references in the over row by using `OFFSET`. Try this instead:

```
=IF(A2<>OFFSET(A2,-1,0),0,OFFSET(D2,-1,0))+C2-B2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a pivot table and there you can do many things.

[image: Pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try an array formula version:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2,0,0,ROW(A2:A9)-1))-IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2,0,0,MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,0)-1)),0)-
(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,0,0,ROW(A2:A9)-1))-IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,0,0,MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,0)-1)),0))
```

or more dynamically using Excel 365 Let and Sequence:

```
=LET(range,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),r,ROWS(range),
SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2,0,0,SEQUENCE(r)))-IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2,0,0,MATCH(range,range,0)-1)),0)-
(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,0,0,SEQUENCE(r)))-IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,0,0,MATCH(range,range,0)-1)),0)
))
```

[image]